# Check if button is down javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a simple way to determine when a button is held down. The usual `onclick` won't do as it's only triggered at the click moment. I need my function to trigger for as long as the button is down.

Is there a simple way to achieve this with vanilla javascript or do I need a library?

Comment: you should look at `onmousedown` and `onmouseup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
document.getElementById("yourButtonId").onmousedown = function(event) {
    //fires when mouse down on button
}
```

Or use an event listener: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

```
document.getElementById("yourButtonId").addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    //fires on mouse down
}, false);
```

For touch events use `ontouchstart`

```
document.getElementById("yourButtonId").ontouchstart = function(event) {
    //fires when touched
}
```

Comment: Yeah it's something like this I want but for touch events. Will mousedown trigger that?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [jQuerys](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) `.mousedown()` and `.mouseup()` functions.

### EG:

```
$( "button" ).mousedown(function() {
    console.log( "Mouse down." );
}).mouseup(function() {
    console.log( "Mouse up." );
});
```

Comment: No need to use jQuery for a simple `mousedown` event, but if you're already using it then why not.

Comment: Note: The question didn't have a `jQuery` tag, thus IMHO, `jQuery` answers are off-topic.